# Liferay find User screenName from User Email

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Is there any api to find out screen name by passing the email address as the input in liferay for LDAP configuration?

Comment: It would be much better to give some more time explaining your problems in the first place. And respond to the answers you get. A good question should help more people, not just you

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get a request object, then do this

```
long companyID = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(request)
    User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(companyID, emailAddress);
    String scrName = user.getScreenName();
```

EDIT : in your liferay control panel/portal/authentication/LDAP, there is field named 'user search filter'

1. use `(cn=@screen_name@)` if your users are logging with screenName
2. use `(mail=@email_address@)` if your users are logging with email address

This way you're supposed to import the users automatically.

Please update your question. According to your tags, it looked like you're searching for a Liferay API. If you wanted an LDAP API you should write it somewhere

Comment: I need to get the User object before importing the User's from LDAP. I beleive the above works after import.  Any suggestions for before import.

Comment: Before import you can basically use the LDAP interface, and standard LDAP techniques, to query for the user and their attributes. But this does have nothing to do with Liferay then... Alternatively look at Liferay's code that imports the users from LDAP. Whatever you want to do with that information (you don't give a clue in your question): Liferay first reads the data from LDAP, then imports the users. As you can override every piece of implementation or service in Liferay, you can change this implementation. But it's hard to give recommendations with the current information you give.